Iterate over a parameter of the function
I have this code that i want to compute for 0 < t < pi with 0.05 step, but each new function is a function of the previous one, and I can't really think of an easy way to iterate over it, any tips?
wf_0 = get_wf_0(xmin, xmax, Nx, neigs, t=0) #Ignore this since it's another function
wf_1 = get_wf(xmin, xmax, Nx, neigs, t=0.05 , wf = wf_0)
wf_2 = get_wf(xmin, xmax, Nx, neigs, t=0.1 , wf = wf_1)
wf_3 = get_wf(xmin, xmax, Nx, neigs, t=0.15 , wf = wf_2)

and so on up to t = pi

Do you need to store all the intermediate values (wf_1, wf_2 etc.), or are you only interested in the last result?

Yes I want to store all of them!

If you want to keep track of the intermediate values, append the results to a list and keep using the last value as the wf argument value for the next iteration:
wf_list = [ get_wf_0(xmin, xmax, Nx, neigs, t=0) ]

pi = 3.14159
t = 0.05

while t < pi:
  wf_list.append(get_wf(xmin, xmax, Nx, neigs, t=t , wf=wf_list[-1]))
  t += 0.05

wf_list[n] now contains the value of each wf_n

Basically this can be done like this:
wf = get_wf_0(xmin, xmax, Nx, neigs, t=0)

for s in range(1, int(math.pi // 0.05)):
    wf = get_wf(xmin, xmax, Nx, neigs, t=0.05 * s, wf=wf)

